# Why doesn't Sprockets find my compiled assets?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have deployed our Rails 1.9.3 application to the production Windows 2008 R2s Server. [Client insists on IIS :-(]. We're using Helicon Zoo, set up the site in IIS Manager, copied the app to the default directory, and ran:

- bundle install
- bundle exec rake assets:precompile
- rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production"

We are able to connect both locally and remotely, but have two problems.

1) CSS style sheets are not available and the format of the pages (not surprisingly) are crap.  The log shows the following:

```
Started GET "/assets/application-af54c6f2f95c6c2f7d965706cab068f3.css" for 10.10.100.185 at 2013-09-16 17:02:27 -0400

 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-af54c6f2f95c6c2f7d965706cab068f3.css"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  ...
```

However, there is a file named "application-af54c6f2f95c6c2f7d965706cab068f3.css" in the public/assets directory.  What gives?

2) Routing that works in development and WEBrick breaks in production.  Here is an example:

View code:
    <%= link_to 'Logout', logout_path, method: :delete %>

routes code:

```
controller :sessions do
  get    'login'  => :new
  post   'login'  => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
  post   'logout' => :create
end
```

Log:

```
Started GET "/logout" for 10.10.100.185 at 2013-09-16 17:04:20 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/logout"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  ...
```

Why [Get] when the controller indicates "method: :delete"?  Why does it work in dev, but not prod?

Comment: I don't get what is you production environment ? webrick or Helicon Zoo ?

Comment: Production environment is Helicon Zoo.

Comment: Did you took a look at: http://www.helicontech.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-on-windows-in-production/ ?

Comment: I have.  Not very helpful.  The relevant bit amounts to"So, at first, we create an empty web-site via IIS manager or your hosting panel. Then simply upload entire web site folder with your application to the server via FTP or Web Deploy or any other way." Did that, but to get anything to work I entered the three commands I listed above.

Comment: Regarding tutorial on `helitech` your first and third command are not needed. At **Creating** part they show how to configure your RAILS_ENV. And at **Deploying** part they show how to run you `bunble`. And maybe you can put away assets precompiling for the moment.

Comment: We developed the application outside of Helicon Zoo and attempted to upload the files into the web site directory.  We take it from your comment that we should 'develop' the application in Zoo.  Is that correct?

Comment: not excatly, more run `bundle` and prepare enviromnent on Helicon Zoo side.

Answer (score 0):

Both are driving you to route issues.

- First be sure about you do not have `assets` controller.
- Then be sure to have good understanding of routes. There is  [good article about](http://www.tatvartha.com/2009/09/environment-specific-routing-in-rails/).
- check differences between your environment configuration files
- consider to read or review configuring [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

I know that is just a check line but that can help to focus on right point.

Comment: Does seem to point to a routes issue, but why is there a difference between the development environment (which behaves correctly) and the production environment as we set it up?  In particular, why doesn't Sprockets find the compiled assets in public/assets?

Comment: What is happening when you run webrick in `prod` and Helicon Zoo in `dev` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Turns out I have a version challenge.  Zoo runs Rails 4.0.0.  I developed in 3.2.13.  Cleaning up the mess will take time.